# Identifying unique users with a certain criteria in all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset where I'm trying to identify situations where a user only has null or blank values for a field. In the example below, I'd only want to count distinct user 3, not user 1 or 2, because not all of user 1 or 2's status is NULL.

What would be the best way to count distinct users like user 3, while not counting users 1 or 2? Thank you. I can't do a not equal to aa, bb, or cc status because there are hundreds of potential combinations.

Sample data table A (not result)

| User_id | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aa |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | bb |
| 2 | cc |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | NULL |
| 3 |  |

Tried various count distinct formulas but not sure how to exclude users 1 and 2, given they have some rows with NULL or blank values.

Attempted result (returns > 1):

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT user_id) as user_count 
FROM table a 
WHERE status IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both anyway, a [mcve].

Comment: And do you want a count of users? Or a list of users meeting your criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with the `EXCEPT` operator, like this:

```
select user_id
  from users a
except
select user_id
  from users b
  where b.status is not null and b.status != '';
```

This takes your original list of user IDs and subtracts away all the user IDs that have at least one value that's non-null and not an empty string.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cbb359/7/0

Comment: For SQL Server I think you mean the `EXCEPT` operator... and I *think* OP wants a count... but they need to clarify that.

Comment: @DaleK, you are correct about `except`. Fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Setup data (always good to provide this if you want a fast answer)

```
declare @MyTable table(UserId int, [Status] varchar(12));

insert into @MyTable(UserId, [Status])
values
(1, null),
(2, ''),
(3, 'a'),
(4, null),
(4, 'a'),
(5, ''),
(5, 'a'),
(6, ''),
(6, null),
(6, null);
```

To get a list of users that match your criteria, use the `having` clause and  check that the `max` status, when empty strings are converted to null, is null. Any other status will fail this.

```
select UserId
from @MyTable
group by UserId
having max(nullif([Status],'')) is null;
```

Which returns:

| UserId |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 6 |

And to count them, wrap the above query in a sub-query/cte and count.

```
with cte as (
  select UserId
  from @MyTable
  group by UserId
  having max(nullif([Status],'')) is null
)
select count(*) [Count]
from cte;
```

Which returns:

| Count |
| --- |
| 3 |

Comment: I think this is the opposite result of what was asked. OP wanted that values that have exclusively null/empty statuses.

Comment: Ah, got it. I misread, and was conflating OP's data with your results.

Comment: Or the more idiomatic `COUNT(NULLIF(Status, '')) = 0`